# If $f$ is entire and $\mathrm{Arg}(f(z))=-\pi/2$ when $|z|=1$, then how to show that $f$ is constant using Liouville's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

If $f$ is entire and $\mbox{Arg}(f(z))=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ when $|z|=1$, then show that $f$ is constant.

All I need to prove is that f is bounded but I can't figure out how. I'd like someone's help.

Comment: If $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-1| < 1\}$ and $C = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| =1\}$, then on $D\cap C$, we have $f(z) = e^{log(z)} = e^{-i\pi/2}$, so $f$ is constant on $D\cap C$. By the identity theorem, it is constant on $D$, and hence on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I don't begin to understand that. Why is $f(z)=-i$ on $D\cap C$? We are given that it is $-\lambda_z i$ for some positive real number $\lambda_z$ which may depend on $z$. Why does that number have to be 1?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$.
Consider the functions $$g(z) = e^{f(z)},~ ~~~ h(z) = e^{-f(z)}.$$ 
Note that, since $u|_{|z|=1} \equiv 0$, it follows that $$|g(z)|=|h(z)| = 1$$ on $|z|=1.$ Thus, by Maximum Modulus Principle, we have, $|g(z)| \leq 1$ and $|h(z)| \leq 1$ on $|z| \leq 1$. However,

$$|g(z)|=|e^{u(z)}|$$ and $$|h(z)| = |e^{-u(z)}|$$

which implies,
$$|e^{u(z)}| \leq 1,~~~|e^{-u(z)}| \leq 1$$ on $|z| \leq 1.$ Hence, at least one of $g$ or $h$ is constant, and therefore $f$ is constant.

$\textbf{NOTE :}$ It is clear that this argument will hold even under the assumption that $f$ maps $\mathbb{S^{1}}$ to a line, not necessarily the imaginary axis. Simply apply translations and rotations accordingly.

Comment: or any closed contour of the complex plane, where $f$ is supposed  analytic on a simply connected open containing that closed contour

Answer (score 4):

The harmonic function $u(z)=\textrm{Re}f(z)$ satisfies $u=0$ on $|z|=1$, so $u\equiv 0$ by the uniqueness of solutions to the Dirichlet problem $\Delta u=0$ on $D$, $u=0$ on $\partial D$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g\colon \mathbf C\setminus \{-i\} \rightarrow \mathbf C\setminus\{1\}$ be a Moebius transformation mapping the real line $\mathbf R$ onto the unit circle minus the point $1$. Let $h=i\cdot f\circ g$. Then $h$ takes real values on $\mathbf R$. It follows that $h(\bar z)=\overline{h(z)}$ for all $z\in\mathbf C\setminus\{\pm i\}$. Since $h$ can be extended over $i$, it can then also over $-i$. Hence $h$ is entire. Since $g(z)\rightarrow1$ if $z\rightarrow\infty$, and $f$ is holomorphic at $1$, the entire function $h$ has a limit as $z$ tends to infinity. In particular, $h$ is bounded, and therefore constant by Liouville's theorem.